# Под фиксированное меню на старте скрола частично прячется контент, как это побороть?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть прилипающее меню, идущее за блоком header (header имеет фиксированную высоту). Проблема в том что идущий сразу же контент, на старте скрола частично прячется под самим меню. Как это возможно побороть? Пробовал добавлением и padding и margin, все безрезультатно.
Код jquery меню:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop()>$("header").height()-$("my-nav").height()){
            $(".my-nav").addClass("stickly");
        }
        else
        {
            $(".my-nav").removeClass("stickly");
        }
    });
```

Вот [проект](http://martynuk.info/)

Comment: Нужно добавлять к html margin-top, рамез которого - это высота прилипающего меню.

Comment: к html? это как?

Comment: Просто к тегу <html> цепплять стиль или класс, в котором будет установлен этот margin-top.

Comment: ну так а он же будет отображаться на странице (отступ сверху появится)

Comment: не появится.... его перекроет фиксированный элемент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как пример, особо не стилизовал, но серый блок отлично прилипает к потолку при этом контент не прыгает. [Линк на codepen](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/grbPqo). И сам код:

```
var distance = $('h1').offset().top,
    heightTitle = $('h1').outerHeight(true)
    $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
       $('h1').addClass('sticked')
       $('html').css('margin-top', heightTitle)
    }
  else {
       $('h1').removeClass('sticked')
       $('html').css('margin-top', '0')
  } 
});
```